# How to find digits (number) in string using Twig?

Tags: symfony, twig

I have product name, which contains only one number.

```
Product.name="Pack of apples (12 pcs).";
Product.price=6;
```

What I'm trying to do - is to put 12 to variable, to do a little math later  (ex: show how many costs 1 apple).

I was tried to do following:

```
{{ set apple = attribute(product, 'title'~lang)|replace('/[^0-9]/', '') }}
```

but with no luck.

I only have access to modifying .twig files, so any workaround would be appreciated

Comment: This is not a good practice. Why can't you have an attribute `amount` or so? (this will ultimately fail, when the product name has numbers in it which do not mean the amount, i.e. "Pack of i7 processors (6 pcs)")

Comment: Will it always show "x pcs"? Where "x" is the number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not reccommend using this way, however in this circumstance, the required data *could* be retrieved using simple *split* commands.

```
{% set bar = "Pack of apples (12 pcs)." %} 
{% set foo = bar|split('(')[1]|split(' p')[0] %}
{{ foo }}
```

This would lead to `foo` containing 12.

However again, this would not be the best way to approach this and the use of an *amount* variable would be more approproate.